# Databricks Statistics on delta table

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Do You think statistics on column generation have sense in delta lake ? Does it optimize joins & aggregations or maybe there counts only statistics inside _delta_log  ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLhHw.jpg)

tryied  to see if statistics have influence on performance
searching alot of internet resources without answer

Comment: some links from here would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881505/databricks-z-order-vs-partitionby/70883660#70883660

Comment: @AlexOtt but does statistics on column created by analyze table... works ? do i have to use this. This articles are more about Z-ordering & partitions

Comment: Analyze table collects more than data for data skipping: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-analyze-table.html - this data is used then for query planning. But checking the answer may help you a bit to reason about performance

Comment: As I understand it, having statistics on a column (recorded at the file level) can tell the optimiser if that file contains the data you're looking for, so it can skip the file. Perhaps to test that it works you need to confirm that with statistics, files are skipped and without statistics they aren't

Answer (score 0):

Delta Lake metadata statistics can be used to optimize different types of queries.  Here are examples of queries that can run faster by leveraging the table metadata:

- `select count(*) from the_table`
- `select * from the_table limit 1`

See [this blog post](https://delta.io/blog/2023-04-19-faster-aggregations-metadata/) for more information.

Column level statistics can optimize any operation whenever entire files can get skipped.  Reading less data always makes queries run faster.

Comment: But I have asked about ANALYZE TABLE tab_name COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR ALL COLUMNS. Not about stats in delta tables. DOes this statistics for columns helps in query times , joins or something else in delta lake ?